# Where is the code from barcode scanner zxing saved?

Tags: android, database, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've integrated the BarCode Scanner application into my application.
Now I want to use the scanned code to compare it with my database and find the product. 
How can I get the code? Where is it saved?

Thanks

Comment: I've done nothing but integrating this: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android                     The problem is that I don't know how to take the scanned code to compare it with my database. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't integrate android/; it's not a library and not meant for this. Use android-integration/.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling zxing in startActivityForResult().  If so then when it is done it will return to your activity in a call to ActivityResult() which will contain the bundle in the intent with your results.  Here is some sample code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966658/zxing-onactivityresults-not-firing) on SO

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan
        EditText passphrase = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassphrase);
        passphrase.setText(contents);
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
}
```

Comment: Better still use the IntentIntegration supplied in android-integration/. It will help you create the Intent and parse the reply.

Comment: Thanks sean for the input, always great to see developers involved in the community!